# unable to start regionservers in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have a problem starting regionservers on slave pc,s. when i enlist only master pc in conf/regionservers every thing works fine but when i add two more slaves to it the hbase does not start .....
if i delete all hbase folders in the tmp folder from all pc,s and then start regionserver (with 3 regionservers enlisted)the hbase gets started but when i try to create a table it again fails(gets stuck)....
pls anyone help
i am using hadoop 0.20.0 which is working fine and hbase 0.92.0
i have 3 pc's in cluster one master and two slaves

also tell that is DNS (both forward and backward lookup working)necessary for hbase in my case????
is there any way to replicate hbase table to all region servers i.e. i want to have a copy of table at each pc and want to access them locally(when i execute map task they should use their local copy of hbase table)
plz help..!!
thanx in advance

Comment: What is the error that is shown in the logs...also if you are not sure about the hbase setup which you did look at http://openwires.blogspot.in/p/hbase-multiple-node-setup-guide.html (yea yea thats my site )

Answer (score 0):

make your hosts file as following:

127.0.0.1 localhost

For Hadoop
192.168.56.1 master

192.168.56.101 slave

and in hbase conf put following entries :

hbase.rootdir
hdfs://master:9000/hbase


hbase.master
master:60000
The host and port that the HBase master runs at.


hbase.regionserver.port
60020
The host and port that the HBase master runs at.

hbase.cluster.distributed
true


hbase.tmp.dir
/home/cluster/Hadoop/hbase-0.90.4/temp


hbase.zookeeper.quorum
master


dfs.replication
2


hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort
2181
Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
The port at which the clients will connect.


If you are using localhost anywhere remove that and replace it with "master" which is name for namenode in your hostfile....

one morething you can do

sudo gedit /etc/hostname

this will open the hostname file bydefault ubuntu will be there so make it master. and restart your system.

For hbase specify in "regionserver" file inside conf dir put these entries

master

slave

and restart.everything.